# Solving PDE's. Intuition for characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I would like to present my arguments for solving the Cauchy-problem \begin{cases} 
      xu_{x_1}+3z^2u_{x_2}+u_{x_3}=0 &  \\
      u(x_1,x_2,0)=x_1^2+x_2^2 \\
       \end{cases}

to see whether I have understood the point behind the method of characteristics. I'm worried that the method has become too "cookbook" to me, and have missed the general principle behind it.

We are looking for a solution $u(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which satisfies the given initial data. The first equation implies there exists some curve, on which $u$ takes on a constant value. The "initial curve" $z$ ( has some connection to the characteristic curve? ) is parameterized $$x_1 = s \enspace,x_2=r,\enspace z=s^2+r^2$$

The slope of $z$ ( again, whether or not this is a characterisc curve is not clear ) yields the characteristic equations $$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=x_1,\enspace \frac{dx_2}{dt}=3x_3^2,\enspace\frac{dx_3}{dt}=1,\enspace\frac{dz}{dt}=0$$

These differential equations can be solved, using the parameterized data as the appropriate initial values. We can solve for $s$ and $r$. Then the solution will be $u=z=s^2+r^2$. But why is it that $u=z$? I think, that initially $u$ is equal to $z$, and then because $u$ takes constant values on the characteristic curve, this relation must hold later also.

Comment: The notation in the PDE is unclear. What is $z$? Is it supposed to be $x_3$? Or $u$?

Comment: I wrote a brief explanation of it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223928/linear-pde-in-n1-dimension-given-t-0-condition/4224078#4224078)

Comment: @HansLundmark I think $z$ is a real constant.